# How to make a dialog appear less busy?

Tags: menu

The right-hand configuration side of my current connection dialog looks reasonable enough at the moment:

[image: before]

However, with the addition of several (very handy!) options, it is starting to look too busy:

[image]

What are some techniques I can apply to make it less so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique you are looking for is called **Progressive Disclosure**.

> Interaction designers face a dilemma:
>       •   Users want power, features, and enough options to handle all of their special needs. ...
>       •   Users want simplicity; they don't have time learn a profusion of features in enough depth to select the few that are optimal for their needs.
>
> Progressive disclosure is one of the best ways to satisfy both of these conflicting requirements.

From [nngroup.com](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/progressive-disclosure/).

How to apply this technique is way too broad to answer here. Also to answer that we need a lot more context. But if you read into it and search for examples I’m sure you will come up with ideas yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You need a “Connection options” link which opens another part of the UI.

Optionally, you can experiment with little triangles for expanding and collapsing sections.

What belongs where can be decided by a quick card sorting experiment with all the fields as separate cards, using optimalsort and asking 10 users to fill it out as they see fit.

Comment: Say `Connection options` opens a little context menu? A no-window-controls thing?